# Can't create time-series raster WMS with Geoserver due to time regex expression issue

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, time-series, regular-expression

I am attempting to create a raster time-series WMS server using GeoServer and have been working off this tutorial provided here:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_time-elevationseries.html

1. Even though I created the timeregex.properties file as indicated then loaded the store and enabled the time dimension, the WMS getCapabilities shows only that the YYYY-MM-DD portion of the filenames were ingested and any HH:MM:SS in the filenames were not ingested.
2. Similarly, the shapefile created only lists the YYYY-MM-DD in the "ingestion" field and not any HH:MM:SS
3. I need to create a regex expression for filenames that have YYYYMMDDTHHZ, but I am not finding any resources on how one would create these regex expressions.

Comment: I suppose that the "ingestion" field in the shapefile is of type "date". The dbf format can only save dates as YYYYMMDD http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.0/server1/dbf_field_types_and_specifications.htm. For HH:MM:SS you must probably change to PostGIS index.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as user30184 says, shapefile can only do date, but not timestamp (it can do date and time as separate fields, but not combine them into a single field).

So you have two options:

- Switch to a database (search for datastore.properties documentation on how to connect to a full DBMS)
- Enable GeoServer special timestamp support for shapefiles, which will allow using timestamp in a single field, but will also make GeoServer generate invalid shapefiles in output (for example, in the WFS SHAPE-ZIP output format), see http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html#configuration